# Having trouble writing a function that puts together variables of two different classes

Tags: c#, arrays, function, class, inheritance

I have a code with two different classes (beside the main program class).
The first class is called "cat" and looks like this:

```
class cat
{
    private string name;
    private float weight;
    private float speed;
    static private int counter;

    //-----------------------------------------------
    public cat()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getcounter()
    {
        return counter;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------
    public void setname(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setweight(float weight)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setspeed(float speed)
    {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    public string getname()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public float getweight() 
    {
        return weight;
    }

    public float getspeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }
}
```

The second class, called "zoo", inherits the "cat" class and looks like this:

```
class zoo : cat
{
    public string[] arcats;
    //--------------------------------------------------
    public void addcats(int counter)
    {
        arcats = new string[counter];
    }

    public void setcats(int counter, string cat)
    {
        arcats[counter] = cat;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public bool iscatsfull(bool limit)
    {
       limit = false;
        if (getcounter() > 20)
        {
            return limit;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public int Getcounter()
    {
        return getcounter();
    }
}
```

The main program looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cat l = new cat();
        l.setweight(50.5f);
        cat t = new cat();
        t.setweight(67.7f);
        cat c = new cat();
        c.setweight(54.3f);

    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to create in the "zoo" class an array that will catch all of the "cat" objects (the bool function is to make sure there are no more than 20 objects in the array).
After I have a working array, I want to create two new functions in the "zoo" class, one that calculates the average weight of all cats in the array, and one that does the same with speed.

I tried using this function, but it isnt working:

```
   public float Weightavg()
    {
        return (cat.getweight())/ getcounter();
    }
```

I tried adding the "static" keyword to the function but that just messes up a different part of the code. Can anyone show me how to get the function to work using the code I already work? Of course, if there are any problems in the code that I'm unaware off, I'll be more than happy to hear about that as well.
Thanks in advance for anyone that finds the time to help ^^

Comment: A zoo is not a cat. A zoo cannot "eatMouse", "meow", "sleep". there is no need for Zoo to inherit from cat. Don't misuse nor abuse of inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, there are a few things that I notice right off the bat. One is that all your method names should be CarmelCased, meaning `setname` should be `SetName`, and `getname` should be `GetName`, etc.

Also your logic for `iscatsfull` doesn't look right. It looks like you should be returning `true` when the `arcats` array is above `20`. It also looks like you should be saving the cats in `arcats` as `Cat` objects and **not** as `strings`.

The `counter` in `cat` is useless as it shouldn't live in the `Cats` class, but the `Zoo` class.

Your `Cat` class can be refactored as:

```
public class Cat
{
    private string name;
    private float weight;
    private float speed;

    public Cat()
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.weight = 0.0;
        this.speed = 0.0;
    }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void SetWeight(float weight)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void SetSpeed(float speed)
    {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public float GetWeight() 
    {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public float GetSpeed()
    {
        return this.speed;
    }
}
```

Your Zoo Class can be:

```
public class Zoo
{
    public Cat [] arcats;

    public void CreateZoo(int counter)
    {
        arcats = new Cat[counter];
    }

    public void AddCat(int counter, Cat cat)
    {
        arcats[counter] = cat;
    }

    public bool IsZooFull()
    {
        if (arcats.Length > 20)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public double GetAvgWeight()
    {
        double totalWeight = 0.0;
        foreach(Cat cat in arcats) // Loop through all the cats in arcats and add all their weights
        {
            totalWeight += cat.GetWeight();
        }
        return totalWeight / arcats.Length; // Divide total weight by number of cats
    }
}
```

You can now work with them in the `Main` as so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        cat1.SetWeight(50.5f);

        Cat cat2 = new Cat();
        cat2.SetWeight(67.7f);

        Cat  cat3 = new Cat();
        cat3.SetWeight(54.3f);

        Zoo z = new Zoo();
        // Create new Zoo with arcats of length 3
        // z.CreateZoo(21);
        z.CreateZoo(3);
        // Add the three Cats to the Zoo
        z.AddCat(0, cat1);
        z.AddCat(1, cat2);
        z.AddCat(2, cat3);

        Console.WriteLine("Checking if Zoo is full: " + z.IsZooFull()); // false
        Console.WriteLine("Average weight of Cats in Zoo: " + z.GetAvgWeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the bool function works perfectly, but when I copy it and try to use it, i get a System.NullReferenceException message on the GetAvgWeight() part, and I'm npt really sure what's the reason for it.. any chance you (or anyone) sees the problem?

Comment: @TonySlepian Did you call `CreateZoo()` before you called `GetAvgWeight()`? The `System.NullReferenceException` means that `arcats` is `null` which means it never got initialized with the `new` keyword.

Comment: I'm sorry but I stil dont understand ... wasnt CreateZoo() called in the line **z.CreateZoo(21);** ? I'm sorry if it looks like I'm asking too much or trying to use someone to fix my problems for me, I just joined a programming behind and the material is for people who had some experience with programming, but I'm still new to this so I'm lagging behind....

Comment: @TonySlepian I Actually had some mistakes in my code. Replace `.length` with `.Length` and the real reason why you are getting `System.NullReferenceException` is because it was trying to do `cat.GetWeight()` when `cat` is `null`. For example, We originally created the array to be of size `21`,  but only filled in `3 Cats`. So once the `foreach` loop got to the fourth index in `arcats` it would try to do `null.GetWeight()` since we never put anything in the forth index. One way to fix this is to put a `Cat` object in each index of `arcats` or simply create the Zoo with size `3`. Code is updated

Comment: @ Jimenemex It works now!! Thank you so much for all your time, also your explanations reall helped me understand the code, thank you so, so much I wish you the best ^^ (: